# closed hereditary and property $R$.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $(X, T)$ is a topological
space and $A \not\in  T$, then $T(A) = \{ U_1 \cup (U_2 \cap A) : U_1, U_2 \in T \}$ is the topology on $X$ generated by the subbase $ \{ A \} \cup T$; $T(A)$ is called the simple extension of $T$ by $A$.

A topological property $R $ is called *contractive* if:
whenever $(X, T)$ has property $R$ and $T'\subset T$,
then $(X,T')$ has property $R$.

**property (a**): if $(X, T)$ has property $R $ and $A \subset X$ has property $R$, then $(X, T(X-A))$ has property $R$;

> Let property $ R$ be contractive, closed hereditary and have property
>   (a). A topological space $(X, T)$ is maximal $R$ if and only if the subsets with property
>   $R$ are precisely the closed sets.

**Proof**. Since the space is closed hereditary, all closed sets have property $R$.
If $A \subset X$ has property $R$ but is not closed, then $T \subset T( X -A )$ has property $R$ and so $(X, T)$ is not maximal. If $(X, T)$ is not maximal then there is $ T \subset T' $ such hat
$(X, T') $ has property $R$ and there is $A \not\in T$ such that $T \subset T(A) ‎\subseteq T'  $ and $T(A)$ has
property $R$; therefore $X— A$ has property $R$ and is not closed in $(X, T)$.

> (1) Why "If $A \subset X$ has property $R$ but is not closed, then **$T \subset T( X -A )$** has property $R$?
>
> (2) Why "there is $A \not\in T$ such that $T \subset T(A) ‎\subseteq T^{\prime}  $ and $T(A)$ has
>   property $R$?

Comment: Where does this proof come from?

Comment: Also, what is "maximal $R$"? Also also, everything else is very confusing. Please go through this line by line and break it down into short, easy-to-understand sentences.

Comment: @dfeuer: It’s standard terminology: if $R$ is any topological property, a topology $\tau$ on a set $X$ is maximal $R$ if no topology on $X$ strictly finer than $\tau$ has the property $R$. E.g., every compact Hausdorff topology is maximal compact (and minimal Hausdorff). The source is Theorem $2.4$ of [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-160-00/S0002-9947-1971-0281142-7/).

Comment: Are you kidding!? If $A$ has property $R$, then $(X,T(X-A))$ has property $R$ by hypothesis. That is just what property (a) says

Comment: @Stefan: No, condition $(\alpha)$ (to use the notation in the original paper) is a condition that a property $R$ may satisfy: $R$ satisfies it if whenever $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ has $R$ and $A\subseteq X$ also has $R$, then $\langle X,T(X\setminus A)\rangle$ has $R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: We are assuming that $(X,T)$ is maximal $R$, that $R$ is a property satisfying (a), and that $A\subseteq X$ has property $R$. Then we conclude, applying (a), that $(X,T(X-A))$ has property $R$.

Comment: @Stefan: Ah, I see: I thought that you were talking about the definition of $(\alpha)$, not the first of the OP’s questions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks, I was not familiar with that terminology.

Answer (score 1):

1. Suppose that $A\subseteq X$ has property $R$ but is not closed. Then $X\setminus A\notin T$, so $T(X\setminus A)\supsetneqq T$, since $X\setminus A\in T(X\setminus A)\setminus T$. $\langle X,T\rangle$ has property $R$, and $R$ has property $(\alpha)$, so $\langle X,T(X\setminus A)\rangle$ has property $R$.
2. In the first part of the proof we showed that if $\langle X,T\rangle$ is maximal $R$, then the subsets of $X$ with property $R$ are precisely the closed sets. (We actually showed the contrapositive.) In this part of the proof we’re assuming that $\langle X,T\rangle$ has property $R$ but is not maximal $R$, and we’re trying to show that the subsets of $X$ with property $R$ are **not** precisely the closed sets. Since all of the closed subsets of $X$ have property $R$, this requires us to show that there’s a subset of $X$ with property $R$ that is **not** closed.

   Since $T$ is not maximal $R$, there is a topology $T'\supsetneqq T$ on $X$ such that $\langle X,T'\rangle$ has property $R$. Pick any $A\in T'\setminus T$. Then $T(A)\subseteq T'$, since $T(A)$ is generated by $A$ and $T$, and $\{A\}\cup T\subseteq T'$. But $A\notin T$, so $T(A)\supsetneqq T$. Finally, $T(A)$ has property $R$ because it’s a subset of $T'$, which has $R$, and $R$ is contractive.